# Force object property with variable to recalculate value

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, dom, audio

I have an object with a property that loads a sound sample via the Howler.js library.

Part of the path to the sample is determined via the mode variable, which can be A, B, C, etc., all valid folders, containing sound samples with the same name, but slightly different sounds.

```
var mode = "A";
$("html").on("keydown", function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 32) {
        switch (mode) {
            case "A":
                mode = "B";
                break;
            case "B":
                mode = "C";
                break;
            .
            .
            .
            default:
                mode = "A";
        }
    }

    dict["coolSound"].sound.play();
});



// Seperate file
var dictionary = {
    coolSound: {
               sound: new Howl({
                   src: ["sounds/" + mode + "/bubbles.mp3"]
               })
};
```

With a keypress, I change the mode variable to the next letter. 
However, the sound that plays is the original one that was generated.

I tried to make it call a function that set the sound instead, but this didn't work either.

I have multiple objects and properties like this inside of the main dictionary object. Is there a way to update the properties without manually looping through them?

Comment: Could you post the code where you call a keypress to change the mode? I think I'm missing just a little bit here to be able to crack this.

Comment: @Kevin added, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, the property you set at the beginning of your code is just a string, it doesn't remember that it was comprised of a string, a variable and a string.

What you can do is use a function instead of a string value.  For example:

```
var dictionary = {
    coolSound: {
        sound: function (mode) {
            return new Howl({src: ["sounds/" + mode + "/bubbles.mp3"]});
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your keydown handler you can do:

```
dict["coolSound"].sound(mode).play();
```